# What do you call a set of numbers with the property that each subset sum is unique?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, number-theory, definition

I require a set of numerical elements on which the sum of some of these elements is unique to the set, that it's to say, no other combination in the sum of elements will result the same outcome.

Assuming this is a common occurrence, is there a name to such sequence or phenomenon?

Comment: This website http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/sets_with_distinct_subset_sums refers to them as sets with distinct subset sums and includes references to several articles on the topic.

Comment: I suppose one could call it "strongly sum-free", see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X97921697 for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

They are called **sets with distinct subset sums.**

There are many open problems about them or related concepts. See http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/sets_with_distinct_subset_sums or Tao and Vu's book [Additive Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521136563) for some such open problems.